# Linux expect command without interact directive not working

Tags: linux, command, expect

I want to login from `192.168.119.128` to `192.168.119.129` automatic and run some commands, so I write an expect script.

**a.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 5
spawn ssh root@192.168.119.129
expect "password" {send "123456\r"}
expect "]#" {send "touch /tmp/a.txt\r"}
#interact
```

The output is:

```
kaiwen@kaiwen-virtual-machine:~/Work$ ./a.sh 
spawn ssh root@192.168.119.129
root@192.168.119.129's password: 
Last login: Sun Jan 22 17:36:21 2017 from 192.168.119.128
[root@localhost ~]# kaiwen@kaiwen-virtual-machine:~/Work$
```

I login successfuly, but it seems `touch /tmp/a.txt` command is not run.

When I uncomment the last line `#interact` of **a.sh**, it works, and the file a.txt is created.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 5
spawn ssh root@192.168.119.129
expect "password" {send "123456\r"}
expect "]#" {send "touch /tmp/a.txt\r"}
interact
```

Here is the output:

```
kaiwen@kaiwen-virtual-machine:~/Work$ ./a.sh 
spawn ssh root@192.168.119.129
root@192.168.119.129's password: 
Last login: Sun Jan 22 17:41:23 2017 from 192.168.119.128
[root@localhost ~]# touch /tmp/a.txt
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Why without the `interact` directive the script work incorrect? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `interact` the Expect script will exit after the last command `expect "]#"` and it'll kill the spawned process. It's just like you close the SSH client application (like PuTTY) window when the shell is still alive running.

The `interact` is a long-running command which waits for the spawned process to exit.

Comment: Yes, I solved, change last "#interact" to "expect "]#" {close}" will work.